# Question regarding the use of the word "that"

Tags: ielts

i was writing this introduction and i don't know if the use of the word "that" really matters in this instance:

I wrote: "There is no doubt universities play a crucial role in educating society".

But then i started to think that maybe it was needing the word "that" to make it better:

"There is no doubt ***that*** universities play a crucial role in educating society"

Does it really matter?
 Now that i'm reading both options aloud they seem fine to me, but I'm not completely sure whether it does make a huge difference

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251703/omitting-that-in-a-sentence) in the sister site discusses some cases for omitting that.

In this particular case, when speaking, I would instinctively use the form without **that**. When writing in a formal communication I would include **that**.

The use of **that** is helpful in more complex sentences.

> There is no doubt, at least amongst the large majority of the population, that the earth is round.

Here the **that** draws attention to the part of the sentence associated with **doubt**.

Comment: Good example to better understand when the use of "that" is absolutely necessary. But about this example, and the two possible alternatives, are both  options acceptable?

Comment: Yes, both are acceptable. In my answer I suggest that using *that* is more formal, and hence I would use *that* in written work. Note here I use "suggest that using", when I could have said "suggest using".

Answer (score 1):

doubt admits of the preposition "that", not always though. You may refer to [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/doubt_1) to see the apposite prepositions used.

Comment: Besides that , (no pun intended), is it all right if i don't use "that" in this particular example? Like in the first example:"There is no doubt universities..."